# Calling knockout.js functions from external script

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

Ok I'm new to using knockout, and I'm wondering how this is supposed to work.

I'm using it in conjunction with ASP.NET MVC, if that makes any difference.

Ideally I'd like to do all the functionality in an external script file. In the script file, I have the following function:

```
function GetIncidentNotes (incidentID, node) {
    $.getJSON('GetIncidentNotes', { IncidentID: incidentID }, function (data, status, xhr) {
        var notesViewModel =
            { notesArray: ko.observableArray(data) }
        ko.applyBindings(notesViewModel, document.getElementById(node));
    });
```

And in my cshtml razor file, I am testing by using the following inline script and associated html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#getNotes").on('click', function () {
            var id = 124;
            GetIncidentNotes(id, 'incidentNotes');
        });
    });
</script>

<table id="incidentNotes" data-bind="visible: notesArray().length > 0">
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: notesArray">
       <tr>
           <td><span data-bind="text: object.NoteID"></span></td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm getting the JSON array back, but then nothing populates my table. I'm definitely doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what.

Here's an example of the array being brought back:

```
[{"NoteID":3,
"IncidentID":124,
"GrievanceID":null,
"NoteSubtypeID":null,
"NoteDate":"2013-06-13T14:25:42.95",
"NoteBody":"travissimantor non non habitatio dolorum Quad esset rarendum eggredior. quartu et transit. imaginator Versus bono",
"CreateDate":"2014-04-23T16:12:01.553",
"CreateUser":"jsteranko",
"UpdateDate":"2014-04-23T16:12:01.553","UpdateUser":"jsteranko"},

{"NoteID":1,
"IncidentID":124,
"GrievanceID":496,
"NoteSubtypeID":6,
"NoteDate":"2000-01-30T13:27:14.51",
"NoteBody":"linguens e dolorum non transit. Quad imaginator Pro homo, quartu Quad Longam, rarendum Sed si egreddior estum. quartu",
"CreateDate":"2014-04-23T16:12:01.553",
"CreateUser":"jsteranko",
"UpdateDate":"2014-04-23T16:12:01.553",
"UpdateUser":"jsteranko"}]
```

Comment: you still need to remove 'object.' from your html template. 'NodeID' is a direct property of each instance of your 'notesArray'. If you want to put something in front of it, use '$data.' ( which is the context implied by default )

Comment: I did forget to edit that part out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was indeed a mapping issue. I downloading the mapping plugin and voila. Working js function:

```
function GetIncidentNotes(incidentID, node) {
    $.getJSON('GetIncidentNotes', { IncidentID: incidentID }, function (data, status, xhr) {
        var notesViewModel = { notesArray: [] };
        notesViewModel.notesArray = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
        ko.applyBindings(notesViewModel, document.getElementById(node));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array here, so there is no text to display...what you should convert your html over to would be something like

```
<!-- ko foreach: notesArray -->
<span data-bind="text: propertyOfNote"></span>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: This hasn't helped. Could this possibly be a mapping problem?

Comment: All the mapping plugin is doing for you here is automating the creation of the observableArray. It would be same if you just had a *property = ko.observableArray(dataArray)* and not use the mapping plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a breakpoint at this point to inspect the values.  If you are absolutely certain your JSON is returning correctly then this would be my next step.

```
ko.applyBindings(notesViewModel, document.getElementById(node));
```

Are the variables notesViewModel and node what you expect?

Comment: node is correct, however the notesArray property of the notesViewModel is coming back as this: `notesArray = c()`